# jQuery: Returning the text from first-child or self

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the text inside an element and I only want to get the text if it's inside the first-child of a placehoder div or if there are no childrent and it's only text inside.
So the two scenarios are:

```
<div id="wrap">text1</div>
```

and

```
<div id="wrap"><b>text1</b><b>text2</b></div>
```

So In both cases I want to get back `"text1"`
I know how to do it with 2 different queries but I am trying to unite them into one

```
$("#wrap :first-child").text()
$("#wrap").text()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#wrap :first-child").text() || $("#wrap").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

As jquery selector expressions give results in document order, the expressions can be combined.

```
$('#wrap :first-child, #wrap').filter(':last').text()
```